# How to show a bootstrap collapse div on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following div and want to show this on button click.

I am using this jquery code on button click event.

$('.container collapse').removeClass('.container collapse').addClass('container');

Why its not now showing the div as I have changed the class?

```
<div class="container collapse">
    <div class="row form-group">


        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="height:300px;">
                <canvas id="graph1"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="height:300px;">
                <canvas id="graph2"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row form-group">


        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="height:300px;">
                <canvas id="graph3"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="height:300px;">
                <canvas id="graph4"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Its throwing an error 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).removeClass is not a function'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to concatenate the tags with dots if they are style-classes on the same element.

```
$('.container.collapse').removeClass('collapse');
```

Otherwise if you use `$('.container collapse')` jquery will try to find an child-element inside `.container` of the type `collapse`.

You also don't have to put the dots inside the `removeClass`and `addClass` calls. Since you remove and re-assigning the container-class, you can just leave it there and only remove the collapse-class.

Comment: thank you @Jan ..its working :).what if I want to achieve the same in another javascript function, like calling a function showing this div in another function?

Comment: You can always assign an id to nearly any element in your html-document: For example: `<div id="my-container">`. And if you want to modify that element from anywhere with jquery you can access it by querying for that id: `$('#my-container)`.

Comment: thank you so much. Actually i am a software tester trying to exploring things first time.